# Is it possible to flow children divs and make them fill an main div using horizontal overflow?

Tags: javascript, css, html, overflow, fill

i started to think about this right now, and i'm thinking if it's possible to achieve just using css, or in need of javascript.

I got an image showing the example here: [image]

Anyone have seen something like this before? Can show me some examples?

Comment: [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)?

Comment: you need a wrapper div with fixed size and a div that holds your items with a higher width than the wrapper.

Comment: Just like that! Thanx!

Comment: Looks like a column layout could do that. Yet the small items to the right seem a bit random.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: Isn't masonry for vertical layouts only? Of course you could adapt the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this effect with a table. as you add items just append a new cell. to have items slight to the left or right just position relative; and left: -some px.

[image: demo toy]

```
.table {
    display:table;
}
.table > div {
    display:table-row;
}
.table > div > div {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:2px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[demo toy/fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrq8Q/) *uses jquery for demo but real work is done in css.